# Missing return type on function.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types

Tags: typescript

como esta?
Tengo este pequenio error del linter, este es mi codigo:

```
class DataServices {
       constructor() {
  // ...
  }

     getProperty = (obj: any, key: string | number) => obj[key];
      
     getMessage = () => allJson;
     
    }
```

Ambas funciones me devuelve este  error del linter [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que hacer segun la [documentancion](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v3.2.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md)  me dice colocar un return pero me siguen dando el mismo problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es un problema de que tengas que poner un `return`. Te dice que no has puesto el tipo de dato que retorna. Como no sé el que usas concretamente, voy a poner `any`, pero es mejor especificar para dar más robustez al código:

```js
getProperty = (obj: any, key: string | number): any => obj[key];
      
getMessage = (): any => allJson;
```